# Auto Layout TextField. Center, top

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout

I try to understand auto layout. I have a Text field with 3 constraints:
- Align Center X to: Superview
- Top Space to: Superview 50
- Width Equals: 150
I have a warning: Equal constraints may cause clipping

If I change to
- Width Greater Than or Equal 150
I have the warning: Width and horizontal position are ambiguous.

I am confused. In fact, those Constraints work well for a button or a label.
- Why is it different for a TextField?
- How to position a TextField horizontal center, top 50, and width 150?

(It seems that I have to add a leading and trailing Greater Than or Equal. That seems redundant to the Width Greater Than or Equal 150. That works to silence the warning but that seems a solution too complicated and redundant. is that right?)

[image]

Comment: UILabel auto-resize according to it's content.

Comment: Is the text field editable?

Comment: Double check your constraints... maybe even delete them and re-do them. The red lines indicate something is wrong. I just tried this as you described, and I do ***NOT*** get the warning (Xcode 11.4.1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUChD.png

Answer (score 1):

It's because `UILabel` and `UIButton` adjusts its size according to its content. In this case, you need to specify a proper width or you can give a leading and trailing anchor with the desired padding.

Here's is how you can resolve your constraint issue in this particular case. Give the text field the following constraints:

1. 50 points from the top.
2. Leading from the super view with padding.
3. Trailing anchor from the super view with padding.

The last two anchors can be replaced with these two constraints:

1. Width constraint for the text field.
2. Centre horizontally to the super view.

Here's how you achieve this on a story-board:

[image: Constraint]

Comment: I think labels and buttons "can" resize to its content. But if I have a button with Width Greater Than or Equal 150 I have no warn as I have here with a TextField

Comment: Ok, I can silence the warning if I put a Width, a Leading, and a Trailing Greater Than or Equal. It works but I still do not understand why I need the Leading and Trailing. It seems redundant and too complicated?

Comment: Giving all 3 is redundant. You don't need the `width` if you are providing the leading and trailing anchors.

Comment: I have tried and Apple gives warnings. Perhaps I should just ignore the yellow warnings that make no sense like those?

Comment: No, you shouldn't ignore them. They will lead to unexpected behaviour when the device you run have different screen sizes. What's the warning you've after giving the leading and trailing anchors?

Comment: With leading and trailing Greater Than or Equal and no width: Width and horizontal position are ambiguous. Try it! It is easy to reproduce.

Comment: With leading and trailing Greater Than or Equal and Width Equals 150: Fixed width constraints may cause clipping

Comment: Check the image I just added I'm providing just the 3 constraints and there're no warnings.

Comment: Note: `UILabel` ≠ `NSTextField`.

Comment: Your constraints work but the TextField changes width (a lot) when the window changes.  I updated my question to make that clear even when I supposed that was supposed

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this on:

- Xcode 11.2.1
- Xcode 11.4.1

The warning **shows** on 11.2.1 but does **not** show on 11.4.1

In my view, even though it is a *valid* warning, it was a silly one and appears to have been removed in the version update.

If you want a **label** to have a width of 150, ***of course*** you know the text will be clipped if it is too long. There is no way around that for a single-line label, unless you allow it to expand outside the bound of the window.

Again, that's a valid warning, but that may be exactly what you want.

If you want a **text input field** to have a width of 150, the text will scroll when you input too much to fit.

So, why the warning on a text field? No idea. That **probably** could be considered a bug.

You *can* get rid of that warning by giving your `Width: 150` constraint a `Priority: 250`. Just single, quick test shows that the field width will remain at 150 even when typing too much text. But... I'd hate to rely on that assumption, and if the field width / leading / trailing etc is related to any other UI elements, I wouldn't count on it not causing other layout issues.

I would say (my opinion only) this is an IB warning that is safe to ignore.